# Why does nginx prefixes the location context path to the root location?

Tags: nginx

I have a simple default website configuration located in my "sites-available" folder in nginx that looks like the one below.

When I try browse to */hello* I'd expect it to serve the index.html file located in the root folder I specified. Instead, it is trying to get /hello/index.html within the root location I specified.

Is there a way to tell nginx to serve the files without prefixing the context path?

```
root /var/...;

location / {
    ...
}

location /hello/ {
    root /home/vagrant/public_html/project/dist;
}
```

Comment: You do know that nginx looks at the `sites-enabled` directory and not `sites-available`? There should be a symlink from the former to the latter for those sites that should be enabled. Perhaps you've edited a config that's not enabled and hence not being picked up.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. As practice, I always work on sites-available and symlink what's ready on sites-enabled (which is what I did this case).

Comment: Did you try browsing to */hello* as you write, or to */hello/* as the location line specifies? (Note the trailing slash in the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `alias` instead of `root`; quoting http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

> For example, with the following configuration

```
location /i/ {
    alias /data/w3/images/;
}
```

> on request of “/i/top.gif”, the file /data/w3/images/top.gif will be sent.